# Whats difference between $http.post of angular vs $.post of jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Whats difference between $http.post of angular vs $.post of jquery.

```
$http.post() vs $.post()
```

Is it $http.post() internally uses $.ajax of jquery or makes its own XMLHttpRequest?

I am facing issue [Angular $http.post method not working for asp.net web api](http:////stackoverflow.com/questions/40155288/angular-http-post-method-not-working-for-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

They are doing the same task, just some difference in the syntax. They will call underlying `XMLHttpRequest` to do request to the server.

`$http.post` doesn't call `$.post`, Angular doesn't depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post()` makes its own XMLHttpRequest just like `jQuery.post()`.
The only difference between these two is, their default request `content-type` while making request,

`jQuery.post()` uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Angular `$http.post()` uses `application/json`